# How to include Handlebars.js in Twig template?

Tags: php, templates, twig, handlebars.js

I am using both Twig and Handlebars.js, and was running into conflicts.  I found two solutions.  Is one considered more proper than the other, or is there a third more appropriate solution?  If my Option 1 is used, are there any recommended naming standards to associate the handlebars template to the twig template?

**Option 1 using twig source**

my_twig_template1.html

```
{% block content %}
<h1>Hello</h1>
<p>{{ someTwigPhpVar }}</p>
{{ source('my_handlebars_template1.html') }}
{% endblock %}
```

my_handlebars_template1.html

```
<script id="my-handlebars-item-1" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    {{someHandleBarVariable}}
</script>

<script id="my-handlebars-item-2" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    {{someHandleBarVariable}}
</script>
```

**Option 2 using twig verbatim**

my_twig_template2.html

```
{% block content %}
<h1>Hello</h1>
<p>{{ someTwigPhpVar }}</p>

{% verbatim %}

<script id="my-handlebars-item-1" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    {{someHandleBarVariable}}
</script>

<script id="my-handlebars-item-2" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    {{someHandleBarVariable}}
</script>

{% endverbatim %}

{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know if there's a general preference, but both look okay to me. I would prefer option 2 when there's just a few lines of Handlebars code and option 1 in other cases (with big sections of Handlebars code). I would put the Handlebars files (option 1) into a folder called `handlebars/`, so that you have `handlebars/template1.html` etc.

Another option is to use a variable expression to output the variable delimiters (`{{` and `}}`, as described in the [documentation section about escaping](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/templates.html#escaping)) or the whole Handlebars expression:

```
{% block content %}
    <h1>Hello</h1>
    <p>{{ someTwigPhpVar }}</p>

    <script id="my-handlebars-item-1" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
        {{ '{{' }} someHandleBarVariable {{ '}}' }}
    </script>

    <script id="my-handlebars-item-2" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
        {{ '{{someHandleBarVariable}}' }}
    </script>
{% endblock %}
```

This is handy if you are outputting just a couple of Handlebars variables so this will be more concise than having a separate file or using the `verbatim` tag.